# How to call a function stored in another file from a Python program?

Tags: python

If I have a text file that contains a python function definition, how can I make the function call from another Python program. Ps: The function will be defined in the Python program that does the call.

Ways in which can be done:

1. Consider the python function as a module and call it. Constraint here is that I have to convert a python bare function into a module which would give errors.
2. Insert the code(function code) into the program that calls the function.

Which would be the better way to go about it?

Edit: Thank you for all the replies. Have shed a lot of light on the initial confusion I myself had. Another doubt would be, what if the person(Obviously, not me) has written a os.system("rm -rf"). And I end up executing it. That would mean doomsday for me, right?

Edit2: As a lot of you have asked me to use exec, I would like to point to the this [thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/ex54j/seeking_clarification_on_pylonsturbogearspyramid/c1bo1v5) and most particularly the namespace problem. It gives user a lot of chances to "circumvent" python. Don't y'all think?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? It's very hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I have a python function in a text file. Eg: def abc(a,b):.. return a. This function has to be called from another Python program. The python function is not a program or module in itself. I am struggling to explain it any further.

Comment: Why is it not in a .py file? They are just text files after all!

Comment: "The python function is not a program or module in itself." Why not? It's trivial to make it so.

Comment: I have edited the question a bit.

Comment: about 'os.system("rm -rf")': You right. Thanks for god, we have privilege system and you can filter command like this or even forbidden module os in that module.

Comment: Have edited the question a bit more to gain a better perspective.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the **exec** keyword.

```
>>> mycode = 'print "hello world"'
>>> exec mycode
Hello world
```

So if you read your text file as text (assuming that it only contains the function) like:

test.txt:

```
def a():
    print "a()"
```

test.py:

```
mycode = open('test.txt').read()
exec mycode # this will execute the code in your textfile, thus define the a() function
a() # now you can call the function from your python file
```

Link to doc: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec%5Fstmt

You may want to look at the **compile** statement too: [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile).

Answer (score 2):

compile() and eval() can do the trick:

```
>>> code = compile('def foo(a): return a*2', '<string>', 'exec')
>>> eval(code)
>>> foo
52: <function foo at 0x01F65F70>
>>> foo(12)
53: 24
```

or with file:

```
with open(filename) as source:
    eval(compile(source.read(), filename, 'exec'))
```

Answer (score 2):

A way like Reflection in Java? If so, Python has a module named imp to provide it.

foo.py

```
def foo():
  return "return from function foo in file foo.py"
```

some code anywhere

```
modes = imp.get_suffixes() #got modes Explained in link below
mode = modes[-2] # because I want load a py file
with open("foo.py") as file:
  m = imp.load_module("name", file, "foo.py", mode)
print(m.foo())
```

above `mode = modes[-2]` because my `imp.get_suffixes()` is:

```
>>> imp.get_suffixes()
[('.cpython-32m.so', 'rb', 3), ('module.cpython-32m.so', 'rb', 3), ('.abi3.so', 'rb', 3), ('module.abi3.so', 'rb', 3), ('.so', 'rb', 3), ('module.so', 'rb', 3), ('.py', 'U', 1), ('.pyc', 'rb', 2)]
```

here is my output:

```
Python 3.2.1 (default, Aug 11 2011, 01:27:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import imp
>>> with open("foo.py") as file:
...   m = imp.load_module("foo", file, "foo.py", ('.py', 'U', 1))
... 
>>> m.foo()
'return from function foo in file foo.py'
```

Check it here: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/imp.html
Both python 2.7 and python 3 works:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import imp
>>> imp.get_suffixes()
[('.so', 'rb', 3), ('module.so', 'rb', 3), ('.py', 'U', 1), ('.pyc', 'rb', 2)]
>>> with open("foo.py") as file:
...   m = imp.load_module("foo", file, "foo.py", ('.py', 'U', 1))
... 
>>> m.foo()
'return from function foo in file foo.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use execfile:

```
execfile("path/example.py")

# example.py
# def example_func():
#     return "Test"
#

print example_func()
# >Test
```

**EDIT:**

In case you want to execute some unsecure code, you can try to sandbox it this way,
although it is probably not very safe anyway:

```
def execfile_sandbox(filename):
    from copy import copy
    loc = globals()
    bi  = loc["__builtins__"]
    if not isinstance(bi, dict): bi = bi.__dict__ 

    bi = copy(bi)        
    # no files
    del bi["file"]    
    # and definitely, no import
    del bi["__import__"]
    # you can delete other builtin functions you want to deny access to

    new_locals = dict()
    new_locals["__builtins__"] = bi
    execfile(filename, new_locals, new_locals)
```

Usage:

```
try:
    execfile_sandbox("path/example.py")
except:
    # handle exception and errors here (like import error)
    pass
```

Comment: What happens if the function needs the global imports?

Comment: Function can use whatever global imports you pass it through globals parameter to execfile http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your purpose, but I suppose that you have function in one program and you do want that function run in another program. You can "marshal" function from first to second.

Example, first program:

```
# first program
def your_func():
    return "your function"

import marshal
marshal.dump(your_func.func_code, file("path/function.bin","w"))
```

Second program:

```
# Second program

import marshal, types
code = marshal.load(file("path/function.bin"))
your_func = types.FunctionType(code, globals(), "your_func")

print your_func()
# >your function
```