# How to import external Python script?

Tags: python, import, external

I am writing a game engine in Python and the thing is I am not sure how to handle external scripts (think source engine mods, LUA). Every scene, entity in a game can have custom script attached to it, but game engine is not aware of those scripts until the scene is being loaded. For example there could be a script, which would animate game cutscene and that script would be used only in one scene.

So, what i want to know is what's the best way to handle those scripts? I know I could import them with exec or eval, but someone said it's now safe. Why? I could also create some scripting language, which would be parsed during runtime, but I don't see a point in that considering that Python is scripting language itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) for this.  Say your `entity` has a `script` attribute that can be either `None` or the name of a script (that is in a known location, which is on `sys.path`), you could use the following code to run the `main()` function from that script:

```
if entity.script is not None:
    custom_script = __import__(entity.script, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
    custom_script.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `exec` and `eval` are not safe for user-supplied data, like handling expressions or Web input. But if you specifically want to give users the full power of Python, and you understand the risks (users can do *anything* – erase/read files on the computer, crash Python, enter an infinite loop, etc.), using `exec` is perfectly fine.

If you trust your game script designer(s), `exec` away. If the levels can come from random people on the Internet, at least let your players be aware of the risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your external script either using by importing it using `__import__()` or using `exec`/`execfile` function. It is nice to know that:

- import compiles script to byte-code and saves `.pyc` file at first usage
- import tries to search for the *module* and eventually it creates *module* with its own namespace in contrast to `exec`/`execfile` that just executes the code in string/file.
- it is possible to sandbox your code a bit by mangling with globals builtins during passing globals as parameters to `__import__`/`execfile`, although this method is not super safe, see my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644657/how-to-call-a-function-stored-in-another-file-from-a-python-program/7644964#7644964) for example.